# A gallery of images as instagram has

Tags: android

[I need to make a gallery for viewing photos as instagram has. If we have a scrolling area preview is scrolled only  preview. If we are scrolling in zone preview+big foto big picture collapses. Part of a big picture visible after the collapse. If we have a click on the visible part of a big picture , the application returns to the initial state. I have tried to use CoordinatorLayout + CollapsingToolbarLayout. But they have a different algorithm from collapsing